# MS-SQL problem - Only one expression can be specified in the select list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I write the following query:

```
select 
   id, 
   (select NameEn from [Campaign] where id=CampaignId) as CampaignName,    
   createdDate, 
   (select Name, IdNo, Email, MobileNo from [Members] where id=MemberId) 
from 
   Transactions
```

and error occurs:
"Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

How can I rewrite the SQL to make it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use proper (`inner`|`left`|...) join syntax.

Something like:

```
  select 
      t.id, 
      c.NameEn,
      t.createdDate,
      m.Name,
      m.IdNo,
      m.Email,
      m.MobileNo
  from
      [Transactions] t 
      inner join [Campaign] c on c.id = t.CampaignId
      inner join [Members] m on m.id = t.MemberId
```

Also, in your original code, one of

```
  select NameEn from [Campaign] where id=CampaignId
```

or

```
  select Name,IdNo,Email,MobileNo from [Members] where id=MemberId
```

might be returning more than one row for each row of `[Transactions]`, which would be illegal.

Comment: Also, replace INNERs with LEFTs if you're not sure whether the Campaign or Member rows will exist.